# clearInterval not working in pause function for game over

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a stopwatch for a memory game. It has to start running when user clicks a card, pauses when all cards have been flipped, resets when user hits reset game button.
As of now, it starts correctly but it's not stopping nor resetting.
I have tried to execute pause() right after start() and the stopwatch didn't run at all as expected, yet I'm not sure the original positioning of pause() is causing this issue. Can't really put my finger on it after hours of debugging and searching for answers online.

This is the whole stopwatch function

```
function timeToString(time) {
    let diffInHrs = time / 3600000;
    let hh = Math.floor(diffInHrs);
  
    let diffInMin = (diffInHrs - hh) * 60;
    let mm = Math.floor(diffInMin);
  
    let diffInSec = (diffInMin - mm) * 60;
    let ss = Math.floor(diffInSec);
  
    let diffInMs = (diffInSec - ss) * 100;
    let ms = Math.floor(diffInMs);
  
    let formattedMM = mm.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    let formattedSS = ss.toString().padStart(2, "0");
    let formattedMS = ms.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  
    return `${formattedMM}:${formattedSS}:${formattedMS}`;
  }
  let startTime;
  let elapsedTime = 0;
  let timerInterval;
  
  function print(txt) {
    document.querySelector(".play-time").innerHTML = txt;
  }
  
  function start() {
    startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
    timerInterval = setInterval(function printTime() {
      elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
      print(timeToString(elapsedTime));
    });
  }
  
  function pause() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval)
  }
  
  function reset() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    print("00:00:00");
    elapsedTime = 0;
  }
```

Game starting function

```
function cardClicked(elCard) {
    start()
    if(isProcessing) return;
    if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) return;
    
    
    elCard.classList.add('flipped');
    
    
    if (elPreviousCard === null) elPreviousCard = elCard;
    else {
        
        var card1 = elPreviousCard.getAttribute('data-card');
        var card2 = elCard.getAttribute('data-card');
        

        if (card1 !== card2){
            isProcessing = true
            audioWrong.play();
            setTimeout(function () {
                elCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard.classList.remove('flipped');
                elPreviousCard = null;
                isProcessing = false;
            }, 1000)

        } else {
            audioRight.play();
            flippedCouplesCount++;
            elPreviousCard = null;

            // All cards flipped, game over!
            if (TOTAL_COUPLES_COUNT === flippedCouplesCount) {
                audioWin.play();
                restart.style.display = 'block';
                pause()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reset on click

```
restart.addEventListener('click', () => {
    flippedCouplesCount = 0;
    for(card of cards) card.classList.remove('flipped');
    restart.style.display = 'none';
    shuffle();
    reset()
})
```

Comment: Since you solved your own problem, please post the solution as an answer and accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the start function was firing on every card click. Because of that, setInterval was running every time and making new intervals without the ability to be manipulated.
The solution was so simple yet so annoying.

```
function cardClicked(elCard) {
// Just had to check if there was an existing interval 
    if(!timerInterval) start()
    if(isProcessing) return;
    if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) return;
....
```